# Setting onClick listener from visual studio designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I'm new to dot net development. Today I downloaded a sample c sharp application and opened it in visual studio. This is a dialog box opened in the view designer:

[image]

I've selected the `Create` button, but I can't seem to find any field for something like `onClickListener` in the properties pane. How do I set it from view designer?

If I open the corresponding `.designer.cs` file in text editor. I can see the listener being assigned like this:

```
        // create_file
        // 
        this.create_file.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(53, 142);
        this.create_file.Name = "create_file";
        this.create_file.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.create_file.TabIndex = 1;
        this.create_file.Text = "Create";
        this.create_file.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.create_file.Click += new 
        System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

But the comments in this file say that it shouldn't be edited by hand. How then do I set event handlers for the button?

Comment: you could also click on the little lightning symbol in your properties window to see the events

Answer (score 2):

You can press on the **`events`** button next to the **`properties`** button

and you will see all the events of the control you are selected

select the event you want it and press **`Enter`** or **`Double Click`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Double click the button in the designer to auto-generate the onClick event or as cmos said above, highlight the button and click the lightning symbol to open all the events attached to the button.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Just double click on the button, and you'll get an event handler for your button to put your code into.